# Cassandra query with index

Tags: cassandra

Imagine I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  name  TEXT,
  tag   TEXT,
  id    UUID,
  parameter INT,
  PRIMARY KEY((name, tag, id), parameter)
);
```

and an index

```
CREATE INDEX parameter_idx on test(parameter);
```

With a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = 'name' 
                     AND tag = 'tag' 
                     AND parameter = value;
```

Is it correct that the index **will** be used, returns many partitions and that these partitions will then be filtered, thus requiring `ALLOW FILTERING`?

On the contrary a query like this one:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = 'name' 
                     AND tag = 'tag' 
                     AND id = some_id,
                     AND parameter = value;
```

will not use the index, a single partition will be found and only some rows corresponding to `parameter = value` will be returned.

Is this all correct?

Comment: Your first query is not valid. You always have to provide all columns of the partition key.

Comment: It does work because `parameter` is an index and because of `allow filtering`. Except for a potential typo everything in the question works, I just want to confirm that I understand why and how.

Comment: Ah, right. My understanding of how it works is the same as yours. But I have limited CQL experience...

Comment: Thanks for having a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understanding sounds correct. Of course using a secondary index like that would be very inefficient. Usually it's better to design your schema so that a secondary index isn't needed for any of your queries.